# Meaning of "on many sides" in statement

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, trumpism

Donald Trump recently said,

> "We condemn in the strongest possible terms this egregious display of
>   hatred, bigotry and violence on many sides, on many sides..."

Most if not all news outlets interpret the phrase "on many sides" in this sentence as referring to different groups of people.  In other words, they say he meant to call out not just *this* display of hatred but other displays by other groups at other times.

But, is it possible from a grammatical perspective that "many sides" is referring to the many sides of "*this* display of hatred" referred to in the sentence?  In other words, could Trump have meant "we condemn this display of hatred *from lots of angles*"?

Does my question make sense?  I don't believe the President has made a statement clarifying his comments yet so I am not asking what *he* meant specifically (who knows?), but from a grammatical/lexical perspective couldn't the phrase "on many sides" *in context* mean in essence "from lots of angles" or "in a lot of ways"?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [video footage of the statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WovvFJKsmc) you'll notice that the second "on many sides" is there to emphasize the (already strongly emphasized) first "on many sides".

What he actually meant and what went on in his mind is anyone's guess without him clarifying this further. It could, indeed, mean some variation of "from many groups" or "in many ways" or both. But frankly, to me it sounded more like "egregious display of hatred, bigotry and violence on *both* sides of the political spectrum."

Comment: Confirmed today: https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/aug/15/donald-trump-press-conference-far-right-defends-charlottesville

Answer (score 1):

To help simplify the question, I think you're asking in:

> We condemn this display on many sides.

if 'on many sides' modifies 'this display' or if it modifies 'condemn'. That is, are there more than one kind of display, or is there more than one way of condemning?

Yes, prepositional phrases like this are ambiguous as to which thing it modifies. But often that ambiguity is resolvable by context:

> I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas I'll never know.

The cultural context leads one to believe that I was in my pajamas at the time I shot the elephant. But the second sentence resolves it to the more humorous interpretation.

So, yes, one *could* interpret the statement as saying that there are multiple ways of condemning the violent displays. It's just that 1) everyone knows that there were two groups, and 2) that the question of condemning violence was not under discussion (surely there are many reasons to condemn it but that was no where near the context, it was assumed that any display of violence is condemnable).

Answer (score -1):

It's supportable that the "on many sides" refers to **the number of groups** expressing hatred and bigotry.

I think his own words in that statement can support it ("Not Donald Trump, not Barack Obama...": two very **different sides/idealogies/people** in his mind.) Hatred and bigotry can be expressed *in many ways*, but *by/on many sides* grammatically refers to different groups or positions.

"Blame is raining down on us on many sides" would imply it was coming from many different directions (not one group). (Not eloquent, but comprehensible.)

> "Sara's story, one of betrayal on many sides, reaches back to the Civil War, and the deal her impoverished parents struck with the devil, in the ..." (NYT) (Goes on to name some circumstances which matter.)

It is clear from context that on many sides means from many different people or circumstances. If it were from one person or one group of people, it could be expressed as "a front" or "a faction" or many other ways.

The major (and I think correct) interpretation is that his comment was tepid at best, and avoided calling out the bigotry and hatred evinced by the white supremacists. While our elected leader is not by any means an eloquent speaker, even he knows how the difference between these two positions. Mostly it appeared to me that he was trying to weasle out of any blame that  might fall on him for rousing such sentiments in that group.

On the other hand, I do think the counte-protesters evinced some pretty malign behavior as well, which has not been discussed at length in the press. But they didn't ram a car into the white supremacy crowd, killing and injuring human beings.

Comment: Great point.  The fuller context of the statement is helpful.  Do you think I should edit the question to have the full statement?

Comment: @User01 - your call. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Perhaps. But ramming a crowd of people with intent to harm isn't done from fear; it's done from anger fueled by hatred. And hatred is fueled by rhetoric. And rhetoric is the only thing the Donald seems to be able to produce.